# Frequency dependent resistor

Tags: electrical-resistance, frequency

I'm trying to create a **real** impedance that goes like 1/$\omega$, that is - a frequency dependent resistor (without imaginary part).
Is it possible at all? If not, is it possible at least on partial domain of frequencies? or approximately?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible to create a circuit using capacitors and resistors, and maybe inductots, such that for a limited range of frequencies, the resistance will be approximately what you want. The greater the frequency range, and the more accurate you want your result, the more complex the circuit needed, and the greater difficulty in achieving your goal.

Comment: This sounds like it could be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/914217). What would you do with such a component if you had one? Design some unusual kind of [filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(signal_processing)) perhaps? Maybe there is another way.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Can you refer me to such a thing? Sounds interesting

Answer (score 2):

There are several well known proofs and designs (Brune, Bott-Duffing, Bode, etc.,) methods exist that can synthesize an arbitrary positive real impedance function $Z(p)$, ie., denote the complex variable by $p=\sigma + \mathfrak j \omega$ then the function is holomorphic on $\sigma >0$, satisfies $\Re {Z(\mathfrak j \omega)} = 0 $ and $Z(\sigma) >0$ for $\sigma >0$.

Being positive real means that the impulse response $z(t)$ is causal, that is $z(t)=0 \text{  if } t<0$ and $Z(p)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-pt}z(t)dt$. According to the Paley-Wiener theorem if a $Z(p)$ such that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{|lnZ(\mathfrak j \omega)|}{1+\omega^2}d\omega < \infty$$ then the inverse Laplace transform $z(t)$ is causal. As long as your prescribed impedance function is rational and when taken only on the frequency axis, including both real and imaginary parts, satisfy this inequality your function can be synthesized using only $R,L,C$, moreover a single resistor is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you are simply looking for a capacitor? A capacitor of capacitance $C$ has the (complex) impedance at frequency $\omega$ given by
$$Z(\omega) = \frac{1}{i \, \omega C}.$$

Comment: I'm looking for a phase-less capacitor - impedance that decreases with frequency but also completely real.